# Moving rows between subarrays

Tags: r, sample

I have a number of subarrays, say 2 (for simplicity), each with the same number of rows and columns. Each spot in the subarrays is occupied by a number in [1, 10].

What I would like to do is move rows randomly between subarrays according to some rate of movement m = [0, 1]. m = 0 corresponds to no movement, while m = 1 means that any rows across all subarrays can be moved.

I take inspiration from:

[How to swap a number of the values between 2 rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805833/how-to-swap-a-number-of-the-values-between-2-rows-in-r)

but my problem is a bit different than this. I do know that sample() would be needed here.

Is there an easy way to go about accomplishing this?

This doesn't do it, but I believe I'm on the right track anyway.

```
m <- 0.2

 a <- array(dim = c(5, 5, 2)) # 5 rows, 5 columns, 2 subarrays

res <- rep(sample(nrow(a), size = ceiling(nrow(a)*m), replace = FALSE)) # sample 20% of rows from array a.
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: when your question is answered mark it please as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is significantly easier if you can use a `matrix` (2-dim `array`).

```
set.seed(2)
m <- 0.2
d <- c(10, 4)
a <- array(sample(prod(d)), dim = d)
a
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,]    8   17   14    1
#  [2,]   28   37   40   26
#  [3,]   22   38   16   29
#  [4,]    7   35    3   32
#  [5,]   34   11   23    4
#  [6,]   36   33   19   31
#  [7,]    5   24   30   13
#  [8,]   39    6   27   25
#  [9,]   15   10   12    9
# [10,]   18    2   21   20
```

(I'm going to set the seed again to something that conveniently gives me something "interesting" to show.)

```
set.seed(2)
ind <- which(runif(d[1]) < m)
ind
# [1] 1 4 7
```

The first randomness, `runif`, is compared against `m` and generates the indices that *may change*. The second randomness, `sample` below, takes those indices and possibly reorders them. (In this case, it reorders "1,4,7" to "4,1,7", meaning the third of the rows-that-may-change will be left unchanged.)

```
a[ind,] <- a[sample(ind),]
a
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,]    7   35    3   32  # <-- row 4
#  [2,]   28   37   40   26
#  [3,]   22   38   16   29
#  [4,]    8   17   14    1  # <-- row 1
#  [5,]   34   11   23    4
#  [6,]   36   33   19   31
#  [7,]    5   24   30   13  # <-- row 7, unchanged
#  [8,]   39    6   27   25
#  [9,]   15   10   12    9
# [10,]   18    2   21   20
```

Note that this is *probabilistic*, which means a probability of 0.2 does not guarantee you 20% (or even *any*) of the rows will be swapped.

(Since I'm guessing you'd really like to preserve your 3-dim (or even *n*-dim) `array`, you might be able to use `aperm` to transfer between `array <--> matrix`.)

**EDIT 1**

As an alternative to a probabilitic use of `runif`, you can use:

```
ind <- head(sample(d[1]),size=d[1]*m)
```

to get closer to your goal of "20%". Since `d[1]*m` will often not be an integer, `head` silently truncates/floors the number, so you'll get the price-is-right winner: closest to but not over your desired percentage.

**EDIT 2**

A reversible method for transforming an *n*-dimensional array into a matrix and back again. ***Caveat***: though the logic appears solid, my testing has only included a couple arrays.

```
array2matrix <- function(a) {
  d <- dim(a)
  ind <- seq_along(d)
  a2 <- aperm(a, c(ind[2], ind[-2]))
  dim(a2) <- c(d[2], prod(d[-2]))
  a2 <- t(a2)
  attr(a2, "origdim") <- d
  a2
}
```

The reversal uses the `"origdim"` attribute if still present; this will work as long as your modifications to the matrix do not clear its attributes. (Simple row-swapping does not.)

```
matrix2array <- function(m, d = attr(m, "origdim")) {
  ind <- seq_along(d)
  m2 <- t(m)
  dim(m2) <- c(d[2], d[-2])
  aperm(m2, c(ind[2], ind[-2]))
}
```

(These two functions should probably do some more error-checks, such as `is.null(d)`.)

A sample run:

```
set.seed(2)
dims <- 5:2
a <- array(sample(prod(dims)), dim=dims)
```

Quick show:

```
a[,,1,1:2,drop=FALSE]
# , , 1, 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   23  109   61   90
# [2,]   84   15   27  102
# [3,]   68   95   83   24
# [4,]   20   53  117   46
# [5,]  110   62   43    8
# , , 1, 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  118   25   14   93
# [2,]   65   21   16   77
# [3,]   87   82    3   38
# [4,]   92   12   78   17
# [5,]   49    4   75   80
```

The transformation:

```
m <- array2matrix(a)
dim(m)
# [1] 30  4
head(m)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   23  109   61   90
# [2,]   84   15   27  102
# [3,]   68   95   83   24
# [4,]   20   53  117   46
# [5,]  110   62   43    8
# [6,]   67   47    1   54
```

Proof of reversability:

```
identical(matrix2array(m), a)
# [1] TRUE
```

**EDIT 3, "WRAP UP of all code"**

Creating fake data:

```
dims <- c(5,4,2)
(a <- array(seq(prod(dims)), dim=dims))
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16
# [2,]    2    7   12   17
# [3,]    3    8   13   18
# [4,]    4    9   14   19
# [5,]    5   10   15   20
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   21   26   31   36
# [2,]   22   27   32   37
# [3,]   23   28   33   38
# [4,]   24   29   34   39
# [5,]   25   30   35   40
(m <- array2matrix(a))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,]    1    6   11   16
#  [2,]    2    7   12   17
#  [3,]    3    8   13   18
#  [4,]    4    9   14   19
#  [5,]    5   10   15   20
#  [6,]   21   26   31   36
#  [7,]   22   27   32   37
#  [8,]   23   28   33   38
#  [9,]   24   29   34   39
# [10,]   25   30   35   40
# attr(,"origdim")
# [1] 5 4 2
```

The random-swapping of rows. I'm using 50% here.

```
pct <- 0.5
nr <- nrow(m)
set.seed(3)
(ind1 <- sample(nr, size = ceiling(nr * pct)))
# [1] 2 8 4 3 9
(ind2 <- sample(ind1))
# [1] 3 2 9 8 4
m[ind1,] <- m[ind2,]
m
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,]    1    6   11   16
#  [2,]    3    8   13   18
#  [3,]   23   28   33   38
#  [4,]   24   29   34   39
#  [5,]    5   10   15   20
#  [6,]   21   26   31   36
#  [7,]   22   27   32   37
#  [8,]    2    7   12   17
#  [9,]    4    9   14   19
# [10,]   25   30   35   40
# attr(,"origdim")
# [1] 5 4 2
```

(Note that I pre-made `ind1` and `ind2` here, mostly to see what was going on internally. You can replace `m[ind2,]` with `m[sample(ind1),]` for the same effect.)

BTW: if we had instead used a seed of 2, we would notice that 2 rows *are not swapped*:

```
set.seed(2)
(ind1 <- sample(nr, size = ceiling(nr * pct)))
# [1]  2  7  5 10  6
(ind2 <- sample(ind1))
# [1]  6  2  5 10  7
```

Because of this, I chose a seed of 3 for demonstration. However, this may give the appearance of things not working. Lacking more controlling code, `sample` does not ensure that positions change: it is certainly reasonable to expect that "randomly swap rows" could randomly choose to move row 2 to row 2. Take for example:

```
set.seed(267)
(ind1 <- sample(nr, size = ceiling(nr * pct)))
# [1] 3 6 5 7 2
(ind2 <- sample(ind1))
# [1] 3 6 5 7 2
```

The first randomly chooses five rows, and then reorders them randomly into an unchanged order. (*I suggest that if you want to **force** that they are all movements, you should ask a new question asking about just forcing a `sample` vector to change.*)

Anyway, we can regain the original dimensionality with the second function:

```
(a2 <- matrix2array(m))
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16
# [2,]    3    8   13   18
# [3,]   23   28   33   38
# [4,]   24   29   34   39
# [5,]    5   10   15   20
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   21   26   31   36
# [2,]   22   27   32   37
# [3,]    2    7   12   17
# [4,]    4    9   14   19
# [5,]   25   30   35   40
```

In the first plane of the array, rows 1 and 5 are unchanged; in the second plane, rows 1, 2, and 5 are unchanged. Five rows the same, five rows moved around (but otherwise unchanged within each row).

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I would like to preserve the array. I will try it out an post here should I have any follow-up questions.

Comment: Is there a way to swap exactly 20% of rows between 2 or more subarrays?

Comment: Does your approach work for an array composed of multiple subarrays? For instance rows 1, 4, 7 moving to subarray 2, provided there are 2 subarrays?

Comment: You might be able to "guarantee" 20% by using `ind <- head(sample(d[1]),size=d[1]*m)` (it naturally truncates, not rounds, but close enough). Currently it treats all "sub-arrays" (third dim and beyond) identically. If that is not what you want, I do not understand.

Comment: That is what I need. Can your implementation be generalized to multiple matrices (but preferably arrays)? That is swapping rows from subarray 1  to subarray 2 (and vice versa)?

Comment: In my first experimentation, it is not nearly as easy to move them around arrays with dim>2. This is primarily because with dim==2, to grab/replace rows can use a vector within brackets, but to grab rows when dim>2 requires a matrix, and I did not get simple extraction/replacement/assignment to work using matrices for indexing. Once that is solved, this should be generalizable. Lacking that, I started working on something that robustly converts a 3+ dim array to a matrix and back perfectly; though it might be "expensive" for large data, it would enable this trick.

Comment: I'd be interested to see what you were able to come up with.

Comment: @JarrettPhillips, see my edits, I think they'll help.

Comment: Looks like it will work, but I will have to test it on my data. I will let you know of the outcome.

Comment: I eep getting the error: Error in aperm.default(pop, c(ind[2], ind[-2])) : 
  invalid first argument, must be an array. Note I changed m in you code to pop. Any thoughts on why this is occurring?

Comment: You are missing steps. (1) use `mtx=array2matrix(ary)`. (2) do row swapping, note you need `ind=head(sample(...),...)` *and* `mtx[ind,]=mtx[sample(ind),]`. (3) use `ary=matrix2array(mtx)`.

Comment: Great! It works now. I was forgetting to do both ind = head(...) and mtx[ind, ] = mtx[sample(ind), ]. Instead of using head(...) would sample(perms, size = ceiling(perms * m), replace = TRUE) work?

Comment: You are correct in that you can replace `head` with `size`, though I suggest `replace=FALSE`, otherwise you may not get your targeted percentage.

Comment: replace = FALSE would be problematic if m = 1. Though I can easily include an if statement to fix that.

Comment: I don't see how. If `m==1` then `size` should be equal to the length of `ind`, which is the default behavior of `sample` if no `size` is specified.

Comment: So, ind <- sample(perms, size = ceiling(perms * m), replace = FALSE) will be fine for m == 1?

Comment: As long as `ceiling(perms*m)` is always less than or equal to `length(ind)`, you're fine with `sample(ind,size=ceiling(perms*m))`. Try `sample(10,size=10,replace=FALSE)` to see for yourself.

Comment: If you are dealing with extremely large numbers (larger than R's `integer`s will handle), then there is a small possibility that the use of `ceiling` could cause an over-count. For safety, you can use `size=min(perms, ceiling (perms*n)),replace=F`, though I do not think it will be necessary.

Comment: Despite employing your solution, I still can't seem to get R to swap rows between the subarrays. It only works within a single array. sometimes no rows are moved. Any thoughts?

Comment: I thought it was doing what it was supposed to, but upon further investigation, it was apparent that it was not doing what I need

Comment: Edits made. Note that "random shuffling of rows" does not mean "all of the shuffling results in a row move". Specifically see my note about "seed 267".

Comment: Thanks! Your edits do help. But I'm not so sure I follow your argument with setting the seed. Seeds are for reproducibility, so I don't see how they have any effect unless invoked by the user. Can you clarify? I have created a user-defined function for my simulation to make it easier for users to run code all in one go. In your opinion, would it be a good idea to have an argument in my function that sets a random seed?

Comment: I use seeds for two purposes: (1) for *reproducibility*, so that somebody can confirm that their code is doing the same thing mine is doing; and (2) to show specific properties of randomly-generated data. For your production code, you should *not* set the seeds, but you should realize that your samples might not produce as many changes as you expect. (My seeds were specifically to demonstrate that `sample(ind1)` might retain some of the numbers in the same positions.)

Comment: Alright Great. Thanks again for the help -- greatly appreciated!! I think I will the separate question of forcing all rows to move at random as you mention in your edit. I am curious about this.

Comment: I thought I would mention that it has been suggested to me that the simplest way of going about solving this problem is to simply use a temporary variable (as would be done in complied languages such as C and the like) in order to store randomly sampled row indices, which is a less coding intensive approach.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand: this approach uses `ind1` and `ind2` as temporary variables to store sampled row indices.

Comment: Correction: one is actually storing rows in a temporary variable