# Moving rows between multiple subarrays

Tags: arrays, r

My question follows from a previous question that I asked, but without including my own code (which I should have done initially).

[Moving rows between subarrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105333/moving-rows-between-subarrays)

which solves my dilemma only partially. But I have adopted the method in the below code.

Here is relevant code to my specific problem:

```
K <- 2  # number of equally-sized (sub)populations
N <- 5 # total number of sampled individuals
Hstar <- 5 # total number of haplotypes
probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar) # haplotype frequencies
m = 0.1 # migration rate between subpopulations
perms <- 10000 # number of permutations

## Set up container(s) to hold the identity of each individual from each permutation ##

num.specs <- ceiling(N / K)

## Create an ID for each haplotype ##

haps <- 1:Hstar

## Assign individuals (N) to each subpopulation (K) ##

specs <- 1:num.specs

## Generate permutations, assume each permutation has N individuals, and sample those individuals' haplotypes from the probabilities ##

gen.perms <- function() {
    sample(haps, size = num.specs, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
}

pop <- array(dim = c(perms, num.specs, K))

for (i in 1:K) {
    pop[,, i] <- replicate(perms, gen.perms())
}

## Allow individuals from permutations to migrate between subpopulations ##

for (i in 1:K) {
    if (m != 0){
        ind <- sample(perms, size = perms * m, replace = FALSE) # sample random row from random subpopulation
    }
    pop[ind,] ## should swap rows between subarrays, but instead throws an error.
}
```

'ind' identifies the rows that are to be swapped.

The goal is to swap rows from one subpopulation (= subarray) to the other as initially asked in the linked question.  For example, switch row 1 of subarray 1 with row 100 of subarray 2. Most importantly, I need to preserve the array type. In the end, 'pop' must have dimensions = c(perms, num.specs, K). Can this be done?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you forget to put a comma. I guess you need to change line 38 to this:

```
pop[ind,,] ## should swap rows between subarrays, but instead throws an error.
```

and when you want to go on with the changed `pop`-array, with swapped lines, you need to store it in a variable. for example like this:

```
pop_new <- pop[ind,,]
```

or you can store it in the same variable, which mean it will overwrite the old content of `pop`. When you use the same vector (`ind`) for index as well the target variable you replace only the old value. With `sample()` you swap the rows randomly :

```
pop[ind,,] <- pop[sample(ind),,]
```

Comment: Right, but my confusion comes from that fact that the updated 'pop' no longer has the same dimensions as the initial 'pop'. What it should simply do is swap the rows without affecting anything else. Since m = 0.1 and perms = 10000, this means that 1000 rows should be swapped at random. The updated 'pop' has dimensions 1000 x 3 x 2 instead of 10000 x 5 x 2 as it should and this is the issue I am facing and trying to resolve.

Comment: can you describe with more detail what you want, because we create it new array with 1.000 lines. because in the `ind` has 1.000 values...before it was 10.000 which means that R put the other values in the other dimensions.

Comment: okay I think I understand a little better what you want...look on the changes I made in the last lines of my answer.

Comment: I think it is working for me now! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Nice. So than you can mark the question as solved, please. And consider to vote up my answer (;