# Forcing sample() in R to sample a given fraction of rows over all of k subarrays

Tags: r, sample

My problem is as follows and I have considered many derivations:

I have an array, say with dimensions dims = c(10000, 5, 2) - that is 10 rows, 5 columns and 2 subarrays.

I would like to be able to use the sample() function to sample a given proportion (say m) of rows in EACH subarray and move them BETWEEN subarrays.

So, say swap Row 5 subarray 1 with Row 10 of subarray 2 (see example below).

I asked a similar question

[Moving rows between subarrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105333/moving-rows-between-subarrays/48106091?noredirect=1#comment83475911_48106091)

and got some great help.

The solution is useful but restricted to random sampling of rows (meaning that not all subarrays will be sampled).

```
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    4    3    4    4    3    4    5    2    4     4
 [2,]    1    4    3    5    4    5    4    5    2     4
 [3,]    1    5    2    1    1    2    1    4    5     1
 [4,]    3    1    1    3    5    4    2    4    4     4
 [5,]    3    2    5    1    2    2    5    5    4     3    <-- e.g., switch this row
 [6,]    4    5    5    2    3    4    1    3    5     5
 [7,]    5    5    5    5    1    4    3    1    2     5
 [8,]    3    4    3    1    3    3    4    3    2     3
 [9,]    1    1    3    2    4    4    1    4    2     3
[10,]    1    4    4    2    4    2    4    2    2     1

, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    5    5    1    1    5    2    1    4    3     1
 [2,]    4    3    2    4    3    5    5    5    4     3
 [3,]    2    4    1    1    4    2    2    2    3     4
 [4,]    5    1    4    5    4    4    3    4    4     5
 [5,]    1    5    5    4    3    3    5    2    2     2
 [6,]    2    2    2    2    5    5    3    4    3     5
 [7,]    5    2    1    1    2    5    3    4    4     2
 [8,]    3    4    3    3    1    3    3    2    3     5
 [9,]    2    1    4    4    3    2    4    5    5     2
[10,]    5    3    4    5    4    3    5    1    2     3    <-- with this row
```

In the above example, m = 0.10, that is 10% of the rows (1 row) in each subarray are sampled and then swapped.

Any ideas on how to force sample() to sample within ALL subarrays? Ideally, the number of rows in each subarray will be very large (10000 or more).

Though I have only included 2 subarrays, where a random row or rows swap(s) with a random row or rows in subarray 2 (dictated by m), I need a routine that is generalizable to k subarrays. So if k = 3, then sampling occurs within ALL subarrays and random rows are swapped with neighbouring subarrays.

So, a random row or rows in subarray 1 has equal chance of moving to either subarray 2 or subarray 3 (it doesn't matter which subarray rows go to, so long as they are always moving between subarrays.  Then, the corresponding row or rows from subarray 2 or 3 will go to subarray 1.

The number of rows must remain constant. For example, there cannot be 11 rows in subarray 1 and only 9 in subarray 2 -- it has to be 10 and 10.

I don't know of any packages that will do this. The goal here is to simulate movement of animals.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is verbose and could be cleaned up, but should get you there.

```
set.seed(4)
x <- array(sample(1:10, 200, replace = T), dim = c(10, 10, 2))
nrows_x <- dim(x)[1]

proportion <- 0.10
idx <- sample(1:nrows_x, nrows_x * proportion)

rows_dim_1 <- x[idx, , 1]
rows_dim_2 <- x[idx, , 2]

x[idx, , 1] <- rows_dim_2
x[idx, , 2] <- rows_dim_1
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out on my data and post here of the outcome.

Comment: Looks like it works, but I will have to do more testing.

Comment: Hmm... Does the code ensure that at least one row from each subarray is swapped to an adjacent array? When I run the above implementation using higher dimensions, I don't seem to notice that rows in all subarrays have been moved.

Comment: No, it will not. That was not clear to me in the original question. Can you edit the question and be more specific? For example, what happens with three subarrays? Does 1 swap with 2 and 2 swaps with 3? Or does 3 swap with 1? Likewise, what about four subarrays? Finally, can you provide some domain context? Feels like this type of problem might be better solved through the use of a package.

Comment: I have added more details. It doesn't matter which rows in which subarrays are moved, All that matters is that rows are moving between subarrays and that the number of rows in each subarray stays fixed.